# Vue.js+Bootstrap: Can't use bootstrap for a specific component only

Tags: vue.js, components, bootstrap-5

I have created a vue.js client side application for which I'm currently developing the admin dashboard/admin panel for management. In the client side, I've been using vanilla CSS for styling elements,made them just as required.
Now, I've created a Sidebar.vue component which is responsible for the routing on this admin panel. Noone really cares about how it looks so I decided I'll be using bootstrap for this and for all the other admin components. I've created the sidebar with bootstrap, using @import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; in the  tag (after npm install). For this page it is perfect, although I realized for some reason this styles all my other components as well even though it is in the scoped style tag. For example, in the Home.vue component, this `<p class="big-text">{{ ("homeBigText") }}</p>` also gets modified.
How can I prevent bootstrap from doing that, how can I achieve it only modifying the Sidebar.vue component?
Thanks in advance for the assistance.

As I said, I tried to include the import in the scoped style tag, but it still resulted in it modifying all other components as well to default bootstrap stylings.